# Consumer rights

Tags: united-kingdom, consumer-protection

I’ve recently purchased a part for my washing machine it did say product out of stock and usually takes up to 10 days but 16 days on still nothing go to tracking and it shows no info available. When I have contacted them I received the following response. What is an acceptable time to wait and can they give me an indefinite time scale?

> We are really sorry for the delay with your order.
>
> The part you ordered is not currently in stock.    We are a company
> who are very dependent on our suppliers, we would need to wait for new
> stock to arrive until we're able to dispatch your order. We
> understand you are dependent on us for this item, likewise as advised
> above we are very dependent on our suppliers. However the estimated
> delivery dates are subject to change depending on availability.
>
> At this time they are unable to give an estimated delivery date for
> your order.
>
> Please be assured that as soon as your order becomes available it will
> be dispatched to you as soon as possible to avoid any further
> inconvenience.
>
> Once again, we apologise for any inconvenience caused and thank you
> for your patience.

Comment: you have the right to not order it.  They can't just will it into existence.  Reasonable these days?  90 days or more.

Comment: Have you paid for the part?

Answer (score 1):

Consumer goods are to be delivered in a reasonable time: 30 days. This assumes (as implied by the question) that the contract has no specific date of delivery. [The law says](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/15/section/28/enacted)

> Unless there is an agreed time or period, the contract is to be
> treated as including a term that the trader must deliver the goods—
> (a)without undue delay, and (b)in any event, not more than 30 days
> after the day on which the contract is entered into.

Comment: But what are the consequences of not delivering within 30 days? Does the contract become void, and after 31 days the customer doesn’t have to accept the goods, or would the trader have to pay damages?